# How to search a text file in Solr

Tags: solr

Here are the things I have achieved

1)Searching from the database and do the autocomplete on the fields.

2)Searching from the CSV file and do autocomplete on the fields.

Now I want to search the text file in Solr how do I implement it? does the auto complete or suggester return me the whole document?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific fields from solr you can use fl.

`/select?q=*:*&fl=field1,field2`

Only those fields you can use it for autocomplete.